# Minus operator used as unary bitwise operation

Tags: c

I don't fully understand how the "-" operator affects the following code:

```
#define COMP(x) ((x) & -(x))

unsigned short a = 0xA55A;
unsigned short b = 0x0400;
```

Could someone explain what COMP(a) and COMP(b) are and how they are calculated?

Comment: Most computers use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) to represent negative numbers. It helps if you know about that. If you take the bit pattern for `x` and `-x` and write them down on paper, and then use bitwise AND on those numbers, it should hopefully become much clearer.

Comment: This is a popular trick to get the "first non-zero bit"

Comment: Donald Knuth talks about this in his lecture : https://youtu.be/o22BAuQj3ds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the "-" sign negative the value of the short parameter in a [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) way. (in short, turn all 0 to 1, 1 to 0 and then add 1)

so 0xA55A in binary is 1010 0101 0101 1010
then -(0xA55A) in binary is 0101 1010 1010 0110
run `&` between them will give you 0000 0000 0000 0010

Answer (score 6):

`(x) & -(x)` is equal to the lowest bit set in `x` when using 2's complement for representing binary numbers.

This means `COMP(a) == 0x0002;` and `COMP(b) == 0x0400;`

Comment: But why ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

`-(x)` negates `x`. Negation in two's complement is the same as `~x+1` (bitflip+1)
as the code below shows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int prbits(uintmax_t X, int N /*how many bits to print (from the low end)*/)
{
    int n=0;
    uintmax_t shift=(uintmax_t)1<<(N-1);
    for(;shift;n++,shift>>=1) putchar( (X&shift)?'1':'0');
    return n;
}
int main()
{
    prbits(0xA55A,16),puts("");
    //1010010101011010

    prbits(~0xA55A,16),puts("");
    //0101101010100101

    prbits(~0xA55A+1,16),puts("");
    //0101101010100110
    prbits(-0xA55A,16),puts("");
    //0101101010100110 (same)

}
```

When you bitand a value with its bitfliped value, you get 0. When you bitand a value with its bitfliped value + 1 (=its negated value) you get the first nonzero bit from the right.

Why? If the rightmost bit of `~x` is 1, adding 1 to it will yield `0` with `carry=1`.  You repeat this while the rightmost bits are 1 and, zeroing those bits.  Once you hit zero (which would be `1` in `x`, since you're adding 1 to `~x`), it gets turned into 1 with carry==0, so the addition ends.  To the right you have zeros, to the left you have bitflips. You bitand this with the original and you get the first nonzero bit from the right.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what COMP does is AND the two operands of which one is in its original form and one of which is a negation of it's form.

How CPUs typically handle signed numbers is using [2's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), 2's complement splits the range of a numeric data type to 2, of which (2^n-1) -1 is positive and (2^n-1) is negative.

The MSB (right-most bit) represents the sign of the numeric data

e.g.

```
0111 -> +7
0110 -> +6
0000 -> +0
1111 -> -1
1110 -> -2
1100 -> -6
```

So what COMP does by doing an AND on positive and negative version of the numeric data is to get the LSB (Left-most bit) of the first 1.

I wrote some sample code that can help you understand here:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/935c3452b31ba76c